# How to draw some characters within a rectangle

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, opengl, glut

I use the following function to draw a string in a point:

```
void print(std::string text,int x, int y)
{
    glRasterPos2f(x,y);
    int len =(int)text.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24,text[i]);
    }
};
```

Now I have the need to draw the string without letting it go outside the bounds (a rectangle).
How do I do this?

Edit: I have looked for the stencil technique in OpenGL,and modified it this way:

```
void print(std::string text,Point point=Point(), Rectangle rect=Rectangle())
{
    glRasterPos2f(point.x,point.y);
    int len =(int)text.size();
    if(!rect.isEmpty())
    {
        glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);
        glColorMask(GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE);
        glDepthMask(GL_FALSE);
        glStencilFunc(GL_NEVER, 1, 0xFF);
        glStencilOp(GL_REPLACE, GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP);
        glStencilMask(0xFF);
        glClear(GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);
        rect.draw(GL_STENCIL);
        glColorMask(GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE);
        glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
        glStencilMask(0x00);
        glStencilFunc(GL_EQUAL, 0, 0xFF);
        glStencilFunc(GL_EQUAL, 1, 0xFF);
    }  
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24,text[i]);
    }
    glDisable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);
};
```

As for Rectangle and Point they're just structs, having these variables:

```
Point: GLfloat x,y,z
Rectangle : Size size, Point origin
Size: GLfloat width,height
```

The code doesn't work, if I try to draw a string inside a rectangle it doesn't stay inside the rectangle.

Comment: In what way do you want it to stay inside this box? If you could explain a bit further it might help solve your problem.

Comment: If the string is bigger than the box, it gets cut.So for example it displays "hell" instead of "hello" if the box is too short.Or displays half letters if the box is too little (vertically).

Comment: Then, depending on what version you want to be compliant with, you look up stencil buffer (for opengl 2.x) or frame buffer object (for opengl 4.x). These allow you to render to the screen and then cut off parts of it.

Comment: Could I have an example? I have found a code but it's not working.

Comment: What are `rect` and `point` when it fails?

Comment: There is also the simpe scissor test, see glScissor. If your rectangle is axis-aligned in window space, it might be worth a try.

Comment: I did it using glScissor, it's way easier than stencil buffer.Thanks, that comment was like an answer.